# Why do I receive lots of ConnectionResetErrors with chromedriver?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When running tests on a django site using selenium and chromedriver, I receive lots of  ConnectionResetErrors. The full error output is included at the bottom. Note that tests pass fine even so - the issue is the flood of exception messages in the console. No ConnectionResetErrors occur when using geckodriver. If I run any single test, the error does not occur, but when I run all tests the console output is flooded with these errors.

I have already looked over answers to similar questions, but I have not been able to find any good solution that is applicable.

My test cases extend a common class which handles setUp and tearDown. This common class in turn extends StaticLiveServerTestCase.

The relevant part of the setUp method is:

```
self.chromedriver = chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
self.chromedriver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

No other lines of code affect the configuration of the self.chromedriver object.

I have tried calling `self.chromedriver.quit()` in the tearDown method, but this just seems to causes more of the same kind of error message. It also causes an error message when a single test is run.

What is causing the flood of ConnectionResetErrors?

The versions are:

```
> python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
3.141.0
```

Chrome: 73.0.3683.103

```
> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)
```

Windows 10 OS Build 16299.1087

```
> python --version
Python 3.7.2


> django-admin --version
2.1.7
```

Edit: I was not able to determine the exact cause of the issue, but it seemed to be related to using chromedriver and Django's LiveServerTestCase. For now, I have stopped using LiveServerTestCase. Instead, I use a Python UnitTest and handle the test database setup & Django wsgi server launch separately.

The full console output for one test with an explicit quit:

```
> py manage.py test main.tests.test_pages.test_request_help
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54845/devtools/browser/1c099597-7692-4fe8-b463-783e501f1853
Testing request help page using driver chrome
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54863)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54873)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54862)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54872)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54871)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 9.580s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

The full output for all tests without explicit quitting:

```
> py manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55279/devtools/browser/78eed288-e607-442a-8657-4439409d5692
Testing about page using driver chrome
.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55309/devtools/browser/2190ae47-c711-41fa-922f-9115d50065fd
Testing home page using driver chrome
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55297)
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55294)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55354/devtools/browser/e94aab0a-fb6b-4950-b8b9-ccee2c601cfa
Testing home page using driver chrome
.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55380/devtools/browser/d82461dc-4436-4d81-b21e-4091e9412225
Testing home page using driver chrome
.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55410/devtools/browser/e7b13108-1259-4094-a8be-7963e19d549d
Testing navbar using driver chrome
.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55444/devtools/browser/941ec710-590f-49f1-9aca-912dd453ae8e
Testing request help page using driver chrome
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55370)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55372)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55368)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55395)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55429)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55425)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55430)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55428)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 38.146s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 1):

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This error message means "there is already one connection here and you are trying to open another one.". Maybe one of your connections staying alive or stuck.

You should analyze your code for this issue on debug mode and try to find which areas of your code are doing that. After find it, try to wait for closing opened connections.